# How do I copy a table from one access database to another

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to copy a table from a access database into a newly created access database.
The code below first creates a new database called `TMP` and then tries to copy table `arr2(i)` from database `fileNameNEW` into the newly created database `TMP`

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim objAccess As Object
Dim dbss As Object

strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\TMP.accdb"
strDb = Dir(strPath)
If Len(strDb) = 0 Then
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)
    Set dbss = objAccess.CurrentDb
End If    

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr2(i), "test"
```

The new database is created, but I getting run-error 424 `object required` on the last line.
I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Is this in Access or Excel, tags are a little confusing

Comment: I am doing this from Excel

Comment: You are trying to use access' DOCMD in Excel then.  Prefix with the Access App, so objAccess.Docmd

Comment: `DoCmd` is not known is Excel. You need to use `objAccess.DoCmd`. And either you switch to Early Binding or you need to declare the constants like `acImport` and `acTable`

Comment: Thank you Nathan, that was indeed the missing part. I got it working now!